# Splitting a string at random position and adding resulting parts to a list

Tags: python, string, list, random, split

I just started with Python coding and ran into something I thought is very easy to solve (at least with the help of Google...):

I have a string which I want to split at a random position. The resulting parts of the string should be added to a list,
e.g.

`str = "abcdefg"` 
should become--> `list = ["abc","defg"]`

In this example it was suggested to me to determine a random delimiter within the string (with randrange), split at this delimiter and put the parts together. 
That works fine, I understood the code and was able to modify it slightly.
However, when the string contains a character more than once, this method cuts at every occurrence because of the fixed delimiter.

How would one achieve the following:

```
str = "abcdabcd" --> list = ["abc","dabcd"]?
```

I was thinking about iterating over the characters of the string, but how would I implement the "split at a random position" requirement?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code, which is commented to your benefit:

```
# Use the random module to create a random number
import random
# Copy your test string
myStr = "abcdabcd"
# The highest value the random number could be is the length of the string
max_random = len(myStr)
# Create the random value using the random module
random_val = random.randrange(max_random)

# Create your new list by splitting the string first by:
# all characters up to the random value, then from the random value onwards
new_list = [myStr[:random_val], myStr[random_val:]]

# This is an example of splitting the string after 3, which you describe in your question
example_list = [myStr[:3], myStr[3:]]


# print it out
print(new_list)
print()
print(example_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can slice the string at a randomly picked index:

```
import random
s = "abcdabcd"
i = random.randrange(len(s))
print([s[:i], s[i:]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split it with slicing and by using `random.randint`:

```
import random
my_str = 'somestring'
random_index = random.randint(0, len(my_str)-1)
my_list = [my_str[:random_index], my_str[random_index:]]
```

Comment: `randint` returns an integer that can include the stopping number, which would be out of range in this case.

Comment: @blhsing you're right, added a -1 to accomodate for that